# Chain rule for a 4D Laplacian

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am struggling with what should in theory be a straightforward piece of vector calculus. Working in 4D Euclidean space, take $x_1$ to $x_4$ to be four arbitrary points in this space, and write $x_{ij} \equiv x_i - x_j$ for brevity in what follows. Working in 4D Euclidean space, I have the expression

$\frac{1}{x_{13}^2x_{24}^2}f(s,t)$

for $f$ an arbitrary function and where $s$ and $t$ are defined by
$s = \frac{x_{12}^2x_{34}^2}{x_{13}^2x_{24}^2}$ and $t = \frac{x_{14}^2x_{23}^2}{x_{13}^2x_{24}^2}$. Treating $x_1$ as the variable and the other three points as fixed, I want to apply the Laplace operator (for $x_1$)  to this expression, $\nabla_1 $, but then to use the chain rule in order to find the functional form of the operator on $f(s,t)$
in terms of $s$ and $t$ derivatives. In particular, as per the paper I am following one should find

$$ \nabla_1 \left(\frac{1}{x_{13}^2x_{24}^2} f(s,t)\right) $$
$$ = 4 \frac{x_{23}^2x_{34}^2}{x_{13}^6 x_{24}^4} \nabla_{st} f(s,t) $$

where (this is the result I would like to reproduce!)

$$
\nabla_{st} \equiv s \partial_s^2 + t \partial_t^2 + (s+t-1)\partial_s\partial_t + 2\partial_s + 2\partial_t.
$$

The most obvious thing to me would be to use a coordinate system like spherical polars and then apply the multivariable chain rule, but the fact s and t do not depend on radial coordinates only (for instance if I choose $x_3$ as the origin in a spherical polar coordinate system for $x_1$'s location, $x_{12}$ which appears in $s$ does not depend on $r$ only). But the fact that only squared quantities appears seems to suggest there ought to be an elegant approach to this which doesn't require pages of algebra.